# A clean tacit version of (n choose k) in J

Tags: combinatorics, j

Listing all \$\binom{n}{k}\$ combinations of `i` is a [well-solved problem in J](http://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Essays/Combinations). From that article, there is this implementation:

> ```
> comb=: 4 : 0
>  k=. i.>:d=.y-x
>  z=. (d$<i.0 0),<i.1 0
>  for. i.x do. z=. k ,.&.> ,&.>/\. >:&.> z end.
>  ; z
> )
> ```

used as follows:

```
   4 comb 6
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 4
0 1 2 5
0 1 3 4
0 1 3 5
0 1 4 5
0 2 3 4
0 2 3 5
0 2 4 5
0 3 4 5
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 5
1 2 4 5
1 3 4 5
2 3 4 5
```

I am interested primarily in clean, tacit version. Here's what I have so far:

```
comb=. ~.@:(/:~"1)@(i.@[ {"1 (i.@! A. i.)@])
```

but that feels overly complex and verbose. Is there a better tacit implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial verb is a good start. Your code could be shortened to 24 bytes

```
~.@(/:~@:{"1~i.)~!A.&i.]
```

A shorter version for 22 bytes can be found by permuting the binary string with *k* 1's.

```
[:I.@~.i.@!@]A.]{.1#~[
```

These are both *O*(*n*!) for *C*(*n*, *k*).

Comment: Based on the question history and your code, I assume you are looking for the shortest, not the most efficient, implementation.

Comment: @Jonah Actually, I revisited your verb and shortened it to 21 bytes ``([:~./:~@{."1)!A.&i.]``